# OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer - rel attribute on a element

Tags: java, html, owasp, sanitizer

I'm using the OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer to sanitize HTML input.
The problem is that the "rel" attribute values "noopener" and "noreferrer" is duplicated or removed by the library.

I have an input like this:
`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">StackOverflow</a>`
and I want that the safe HTML remains the same, because it's valid.

This is an example class to reproduce the problem:

```
import org.owasp.html.HtmlPolicyBuilder;
import org.owasp.html.PolicyFactory;

public class HtmlSanitizerError {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PolicyFactory policyFactory = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
                .allowElements("a")
                .allowUrlProtocols("https")
                .skipRelsOnLinks("noopener", "noreferrer")   // with this line the "rel" attribute will be removed
                                                                        // without this line the "rel" attribute values will be duplicated 
                .allowAttributes("href", "rel", "target").onElements("a")
                .toFactory();

        String html = "<a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">StackOverflow</a>";

        String safeHTML = policyFactory.sanitize(html);

        System.out.println(safeHTML);
    }

}
```

I already see this similar issue on StackOverflow, but it didn't solve my problem: [Java - Owasp Html Sanitizer shows double noopener noreferrer for url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661369/java-owasp-html-sanitizer-shows-double-noopener-noreferrer-for-url)